# Apache Virtual Host Not Matching ServerAlias

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, https

I have a `VirtualHost` block defined like this for a domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com:443
    ServerAlias www.example.com:443
```

If I use this URL, `https://example.com/`, the site loads as expected. When I use this URL, `https://www.example.com/`, Apache is delivering the content and SSL certificate for the very first virtual host defined in my config.

I understand the definition order of virtual hosts is significant, so it seems to me that the `ServerAlias` directive is not being matched for some reason. My web searches haven't turned up a clue for how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't care to read documentation on the [`ServerAlias` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) and therefore you have a **wrong syntax**.

```
ServerAlias hostname [hostname] ...
```

That's different from [`ServerName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) that can have *optional* port and scheme, but only one hostname:

```
ServerName [scheme://]fully-qualified-domain-name[:port]
```

Comment: I've been creating `VirtualHost` blocks using a template that I inherited. Removing the port from the ServerAlias indeed fixed the problem. All of the other sites in the configuration are configured with the ports and are working. I'm quite puzzled, but grateful for your solution.

Comment: It appears that the `:443` in my `ServerName` directive is also unnecessary.